# Adding array as a property in greenDAO entity

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

I have the following JSON response that I wish to map into my entity:

```
{
"name": "Andrew",
"stop_ids": [
  "956",
  "957",
  "958"
]
}
```

I know that I can create a one to many relationship if I create another entity with my `stop_ids`, but is there a way to map this directly?

Here's my code below, and I don't know how to directly map the array below as my property.

```
Entity person = schema.addEntity("person");
person.addStringProperty("name");
person.addArrayProperty("stop_ids");  //what is the correct way to do this?
```

Comment: how did you solve this ? i am trying to implement the exact same thing , could you help ?

Answer (score 0):

GreenDAO does not support adding arrays or lists of primitive types directly to an entity. 
Source: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/285

This stems from the fact that SQL does not support this behaviour.
A 1-m (one to many) relationship between entities should be used instead.
GreenDAO documentation: http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/#Modelling_To-Many_Relations